# Record count int value displays correctly in development mode but incorrectly in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

- I'm getting a count for records for a table in the View Model and assigning this value to a ViewBag in the OnActionExecuting(...) method inside the main Controller.
- I'm then displaying this value in Razor code. The record count value is displaying correctly in development mode, but is not correct in Production mode. Has anyone come across this ?

Here's my code:

(1) Method implemented in View Model:

```
public static int GetNewMessagesCount()
    {
        int count = 0;
        using (DatingContext _db = new DatingContext())
        {
            count = _db.Messages.Where(U => U.ReceiverUserID == UserManager.User.Id &&
                                            U.MessageReadOrNot == false).ToList()
                                                                        .Count();
        }           

        return count;
    }
```

(2) Code inside the OnActionExecuting(..) method of the main Controller:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ViewBag.TotalNewMessages = MessageViewModel.GetNewMessagesCount();

        }
        else
            ViewBag.TotalNewMessages = 0;
    }
```

(3) ViewBag.TotalNewMessages used in the _LayoutPage.cshtml page:

```
if ( ViewBag.TotalNewMessages != 0 ){ 
      <a href="@Url.Action("Messages", "User")" class="menubaroption"><b>Messages (@ViewBag.TotalNewMessages)</b></a>
}
else{                        
      <a href="@Url.Action("Messages", "User")" class="menubaroption">Messages</a>
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that the record count value is correct when I view the site hosted on development server. However, when the same code is used in the Production Server, the site displays a totally different value of the ViewBag.TotalNewMessages. I have already checked the record count in the production database table and for example, if the GetMessagesCount() returns a zero value, then the ViewBag.TotalNewMessages will display 3.

Comment: why not use custom model to pass the data rather then using with Viewbag

Comment: @SmitPatel: Presumably because it needs to work on different actions that have different models.

Comment: I would really recommend *never* using the ViewBag and instead using the M in MVC (model) by [creating a viewmodel](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller).

Comment: @ErikPhilips: when I call the Model in _LayoutPage.cshtml, the site crashes. This is why I resorted to this way. *@model xyz.Models.MessageViewModel* makes the site crash. Maybe Models are not handled by _LayoutPage.cshtml ?

Comment: Can you profile your DB? Make sure the call looks right?

Comment: Models work in base layouts if you pass correct model type. You can either implement same interface for these viewmodels or make use of RenderAction method. Most likely the issue is connected with ViewBag usage.

Comment: Thank you @raderick. I will implement what you suggested and will not use the ViewBag. Thanks to all for the comments. I am going to do what raderick suggested.